# How many edges in dense graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, complexity-theory

I have read that in the dense graph, the number of edges is `(n^2)` and I don't know-how 
If I have a graph and every node connected to other all nodes then the number edges will be `( (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ..... + 1)` so, how the edges in dense graph are `(n^2)`

Comment: They should have said [O(n^2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The exact number is a little less than half of n^2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether your graph is directed.  In an undirected dense graph, the number of edges is *(n · (n − 1) / 2)* (which is equal to your series).  In a directed graph, the number is double that, so just *(n · (n − 1))*.

This is not exactly *(n²)*, but very close to it.  You can say that *n²* is an upper bound, so it is maybe more appropriate to say *O(n²)* if that makes sense in the context.

Comment: Indeed, n² is not the exact number of edges but the order of magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

It's the [Big O notation](http://Big%20O%20notation), maybe what they mean is the complexity when you do a graph traversal.
In Big O notation : O(n²/2) = O(n²)